# CSS Grid: Make grid-cell only as wide as max-content, but never wider than 1fr. Or would display: flex be able to solve this?

Tags: css, css-grid

How do I make it so a cell in a grid is only as wide as its `max-content`, but never overflows the parent grid container?

Check this example:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content max-content;
  width: 120px;
}

label {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><label for="foo">foo label, must not overflow parent grid!</label>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" /><label for="bar">bar label</label>
</div>
```

The code sample also shows my real-world use case. I need it so the label is restricted to the parent element, while also not being any wider than necessary, because I don't want white-space to the right side of the label be part of the clickable area.

If I set it to `1fr` instead of `max-content`, the label covers the whole rest of the container, which is unwanted because now you can toggle the checkbox clicking the whitespace right of the label.

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  width: 120px;
}

label {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><label for="foo">foo label, must not overflow parent grid!</label>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" /><label for="bar">bar label</label>
</div>
```

CSS would offer a solution here

```
min(max-content, 1fr)
```

but unfortunately `max-content` cannot be used in the `min()`-function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*If I set it to 1fr instead of max-content, [...] now you can toggle the checkbox clicking the whitespace right of the label.*"? In your second snippet, the only way I can get the checkbox to toggle is clicking on the yellow part (or the checkbox itself obviously!)

Comment: The yellow part that does not have letters is still whitespace, no matter the color. The term whitespace says nothing about the color.

Comment: Ah I understand now - I realise that "whitespace" doesn't necessarily mean white (I've commented many times to that effect here myself)... I thought you were referring to the first label which had no whitespace, so I was confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fit-content(100%)` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#track-sizes)</sup>

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content fit-content(100%);
  width: 120px;
}

label {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><label for="foo">foo label, must not overflow parent grid!</label>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" /><label for="bar">bar label</label>
</div>
```

With flexbox it's a trivial task because all you need is to make the element a flexbox container:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  width: 120px;
}

label {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><label for="foo">foo label, must not overflow parent grid!</label>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" /><label for="bar">bar label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is even better than the solution I found, because this also works as intended if I swap checkbox and label. Thanks alot, again!

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with the snippet, I found a working solution, using

```
justify-self: start;
max-width: 100%;
```

alongside with `1fr` for the label column:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  width: 120px;
}

label {
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-self: start;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><label for="foo">foo label, must not overflow parent grid!</label>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" /><label for="bar">bar label</label>
</div>
```